# Concerns about Exceeding Current Rating on SN74HC595N to drive LEDs

Tags: led, reliability, 74hc595, over-current, current-rating

I am currently working on a project where I am utilizing SN74HC595N shift registers to drive multiple LEDs. According to the datasheet, the maximum output per pin is specified as 35 mA, with a maximum package rating of 70 mA. Each LED is configured with a 3V forward voltage (Vf) and an 82-ohm resistor, resulting in a current draw of approximately 18-19 mA.

Considering that I have eight of these LEDs connected to a single SN74HC595N, the cumulative current draw appears to exceed the specified package rating. However, during practical testing where the chip was operated at maximum output for an extended period, I observed no issues - no overheating or malfunctions.

My concern is whether this setup could potentially cause long-term reliability issues or if there are other factors I should be considering. Has anyone else encountered a similar situation, and are there any recommendations for addressing or mitigating this apparent deviation from the datasheet specifications?

(EDIT)
Context I should add, this is NOT a production situation, I'm just making 1 of this project, and the reason I'm pushing my luck is because the chips are running on a 1/8 duty cycle, and the brightness of the LEDs at that duty cycle is dimmed a lot, so I'm getting pushy with their current

Comment: If one LED is connected to one of each eight outputs of the SN74HC595N and not more than three outputs are drawing about 19 mA at a time, it is OK. But it should be not more than than three outputs active at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, no doubt about it, exceeding absolute maximum limits can potentially cause long term reliability issues and even damage.

If you tested on one chip or few chips from the same batch, it does not mean another chip or any of the chips from another batch will work, or any chip from another manufacturer.

You really should not be in a situation where you need to break datasheet limits and recommendations.

Chips have specified operating conditiond and absolute maximum ratings. They are guaranteed to work within given specs when operated within the given operating conditions. Chips are not guaranteed to work outside given operating conditions, but they also do not damage as long as operated below absolute maximum ratings. They also don't necessarily blow up immediately if absolute maximum ratings are exceeded even by slight amount, but the chip can simply degrade much faster than intended. It might work only for a year instead of 20-30 years, depending on which ratings are exceeded and by how much.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you tried it in one setup with one specific chip doesn't mean that it will work in all setups or for all chips. Did you test the setup at the maximum expected operating temperature?  With the maximum allowable input voltage?  You're more than doubling the absolute maximum limit; maybe this chip just used the last of a batch of one design of lead frame and the next won't.

If you're putting this device into production, imagine devices coming back from the field; the chip manufacturer will point to the datasheet and you will be explaining to some pretty angry people why you thought you knew better than *the people who made the chip*.

Just use a shift-register type LED driver chip. It will reduce your part count and give you as good if not better current matching between LEDs.

Comment: I certainly agree. I wouldn't even dream of doing this in production, but this is a hobby project, I will make only this unit of the project for myself and order no more batches of chips, the setup I tested is a prototype of the exact setup the final product will be and at room temperature which is all I expect, and the test went for several hours. I don't have official production experience, I'm just wondering "Why isn't it exploding when I'm so far above the maximum?". If the answer is that I can't rely on consistency anymore, that makes sense

Comment: Exceeding absolute maximum limits isn't always "instant death" but can cause damage that manifests later. Or sometimes a manufacturer will make one single design that it sells at different specs and price points because it's cheaper overall to do that instead of a separate production line for a slightly worse product.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need that much current drive to the LED?

Modern blue or white LEDs (They have 3V Vf) are very efficient and I would expect that increasing the resistor value to bring the current down to abut 8mA each would hardly be noticed visually. For example a 220 ohm resistor.

That would bring the maximum current down to a level within the capability of the shift register.

For indicator purposes in normal room lighting I normally only use 1-2mA and find them quite adequate.

Comment: The thing is, this is a matrix with 8 of these chips running on a 1/8th duty cycle, drastically decreasing their perceived brightness, leading me to want to push my luck

Comment: @HydroPage That's important information which you should add to the question.